# Add additional string before an url

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to add an additional string before the URL, because the scrapped URL is not correct, because i need to extract the data from the bad URL.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import sqlite3
def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata
soup = make_soup("https://saturn.etat.lu/tapes/tapes_fr_lst_pdt.jsp?sel=_")
allrecords = soup.findAll('tr')
recordsLength = len(allrecords)
for index in range(3, recordsLength):
    record = allrecords[index].find_all('a')
    agri= [record[1].get('href')]   
    for url in agri:
        agripage=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        soup1=BeautifulSoup(agripage,"html.parser")
```

I get the following error:

```
unknown url type: 'tapes_fr_nfo_lap.jsp?pdt=1838&lmz=0'
```

Comment: So `url` is  'tapes_fr_nfo_lap.jsp?pdt=1838&lmz=0' and you want to make that a real URL?

Comment: `url = "https://saturn.etat.lu/tapes/" + url`  - perhaps?

Comment: yes i want the same as you purposed